# Add column/s on insert if column does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql

So I have some data that i want to put into SQL as a test, after wards i want to congregate the data in graphana.

It is of the following form:

a_files, a_lines, a_directories, b_files, b_lines, b_directories, c_files, c_lines, c_directories, d_files, d_lines, d_directories ... x_files, x_lines, x_directories

I'm doing an INSERT but the columns might not exist.
ALTER_TABLE seem to need to know the column names upfront.
There might also be other columns added since we might have z and y added in the future.

Is there a simple way to create the necessary columns as they are inserted.

Going forward to an end solution this seems a little against the grain. (I remember something about using a foreign key to tie them to a row in another table), but it's just for testing the initial solution, as we don't know what combination we might need.

We are using postgres.

Comment: Consider to use single JSON(B) column or array of composite type.

Comment: There isn't a way to dynamically create columns "as you need them"; the closest thing would be using a single column with a `jsonb` type and storing your actual fields under JSON keys within that - ie. `{"a_files":"/filename",...}`. Looking at the columns, I would strongly suggest that a normalized structure with 2 tables is the way to go here - one table would be your "record_header" table, and the 2nd would look something like: `record_hearder_id foreign key record_header(id), files varchar, lines varchar, directories varchar)`. You'll might need a sequence field also to preserve the order.